# C thread not behaving correctly - simple code

Tags: c, multithreading, winapi

I am creating a new thread in c using _beginthreadex. I have written the following code.
same code written in two versions, first version is working properly but second one is not working.

**working code**

main.c

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

extern void func(unsigned (__stdcall *SecondThreadFunc)( void* ));

int main()
{ 
    func(NULL);
}
```

second.c

```
#include<Windows.h>

//when thread start routine is declared in the same file new thread is running fine...
//but if this routine is moved to main.c and passed as parameter to func new thread is not working
unsigned __stdcall SecondThreadFunc( void* pArguments )
{
    printf( "In second thread...\n ");
    return 0;
} 


void func(unsigned (__stdcall *SecondThreadFunc)( void* ))
{
    HANDLE hThread;
    printf( "Creating second thread...\n" );

    // Create the second thread.
    hThread = (HANDLE)_beginthreadex( NULL, 0, &SecondThreadFunc, NULL, 0, NULL );

    // Wait until second thread terminates.
    WaitForSingleObject( hThread, INFINITE );
}
```

**Not working code(Below)**

main.c

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <process.h>


extern void func(unsigned (__stdcall *SecondThreadFunc)( void* ));

unsigned __stdcall SecondThreadFunc( void* pArguments )
{
    printf( "In second thread...\n ");
    return 0;
} 

int main()
{ 
    func(SecondThreadFunc);
}
```

second.c

```
#include<Windows.h>

void func(unsigned (__stdcall *SecondThreadFunc)( void* ))
{
    HANDLE hThread;
    printf( "Creating second thread...\n" );

    // Create the second thread.
    hThread = (HANDLE)_beginthreadex( NULL, 0, &SecondThreadFunc, NULL, 0, NULL );

    // Wait until second thread terminates.
    WaitForSingleObject( hThread, INFINITE );
}
```

I am getting access violation inside _beginthreadex while calling SecondThreadFunc. Can some help me out. Thanks in advance.

Comment: printf() etc stdio functions are not thread safe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the not working code you should have (pay attention to the &s):

```
hThread = (HANDLE)_beginthreadex( NULL, 0, SecondThreadFunc, NULL, 0, NULL );
```

Comment: both are function calls but why the above correction is working...
in c function pointer need not use & when passing to a function. Is that correct?

Comment: @Vineel Kumar Reddy: The change to the `func()` call is unnecessary, for the reason you state.  The second change, however, is necessary - the `SecondThreadFunc` in `func()` is a function pointer value, so when you take its address you get the address of a function pointer, not the address of a function.  In this case, `SecondThreadFunc` and `*SecondThreadFunc` are the equivalent expressions.

Comment: U r awesome though i have been programming in c from 6 year this is really a very subtle example. Thanks a  lot